# React Native SearchBar Error: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `value` of type `array` supplied to `ForwardRef(TextInput)`, expected `string`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have no idea what this error means. Everything was working fine a while ago and I didn't touch this code. I came back to this page and I get this error:

```
Failed prop type: Invalid prop `value` of type `array` supplied to `ForwardRef(TextInput)`, expected `string`
```

This has to have something to do with the searchbar but I have no idea what.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, FlatList, SafeAreaView, Image } from 'react-native';
import { Card, SearchBar } from 'react-native-elements'
import { styles } from './styles.js';

const FormsScreen = ({navigation, route}) => {

  const [formsArray, setFormsArray] = useState([]);
  const [search, setSearch] = useState([null]);
  
  //Fetch all users from database
  useEffect(() =>{
    fetch('http://10.0.2.2:5000/forms').then(response =>{
      if(response.ok){
        return response.json();
      }
    }).then(data => setFormsArray(data));
  }, []);


  return (

      <SafeAreaView>
        <SearchBar
        placeholder="Type Here..."
        onChangeText={ (text) => {setSearch({text}); } }
        value={search}
      />
   
        <FlatList 
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.ID.toString() }
        // style = {styles.List}
        data={formsArray}
        renderItem={({item}) => (
          <Card>
            <Card.Title>{item.ID}</Card.Title>
            <Card.Divider/>
            <View style={styles.Container}>
              <Text>{item.Comments}</Text>
              {/* <Image source={require('./System apps/Media Manager/Gallery/AppPhotos/45e5cefd-7798-4fe9-88de-86a0a15b7b9f.jpg')} /> */}
              <Text>{item.RoadName}</Text>
            </View>

            <View style={styles.ListContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.LabelText}>Name</Text>
              <Text style={styles.LabelText}>Phone</Text>
              <Text style={styles.LabelText}>Email</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.ListContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.CardText}>{item.Name}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.CardText}>{item.Phone}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.CardText}>{item.Email}</Text>
            </View>
          </Card>
        )}
        />
     </SafeAreaView>

  );
}

export default FormsScreen;
```

What exactly is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this

```js
const [search, setSearch] = useState({text: ''});



<SearchBar
        placeholder="Type Here..."
        onChangeText={ (text) => {setSearch({text}); } }
        value={search.text}
      />
```

Comment: For some reason my project has lost its colors file so I can't start my app right now. I will try this as soon as I get it fixed.